# Azure app service custom domain is not working with www prefix

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have a custom domain within my app service, but can't access my web app with www prefix only without. I get error ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED when trying to access with www prefix. I define my custom domain as subdomain.domain.com

Comment: Did you add www to your nameserver?

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly this is caused by a one of the below:

1. Is your **App Service Plan** scaled to allow *Custom Domains / SSL*?
2. Have you mapped the **Custom Domain** to the Domain?

   - For Example: have you created a *CNAME* or *A* Record on **Azure DNS** or your DNS Server?
3. Has it been added to the *Custom Domains* setting of the App Service?

Microsoft documentation for this is pretty good and the link for this is:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain

*Assuming, that you already own the Domain etc etc*